# Need to combine two uploaded images on the fly into one bigger image in Classic ASP & .Net mixed app

Tags: .net, vb.net, image-processing, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP application running on IIS 7.5 (Windows Server 2008r2).
What I need is actually pretty simple:

(1) Users upload an image.

(2) First thing is I want to dupe the image they uploaded so I have a "virgin" version and a "version we can play with". Everything below will be working on the "version we can play with" (the new/duped version).

(3) Resize the image to be 450w x 253h.

(4) I want to create a new image that is the same width as the old one but twice as tall (450w x 506h). I want to then copy the old image, putting one version of it above an exact duplicate; thus making the new image that is twice as tall as the original. Sort of like mirroring.

Preferred if there is a way to do this without a commercial component, like with .Net and I can call the .Net page/functions from my Classic ASP. My experience/knowledge is with vbScript (ASP) and barely any experience with VB in .Net.

Here is an image I made to try to explain what I'm doing:
[image of what I'm looking to build on the fly http://www.casemodo.com/images/image_build_on_the_fly.jpg](http://www.casemodo.com/images/image_build_on_the_fly.jpg)

On this site I saw someone provide a solution for stacking images side-by-side instead of one-on-top-of-the-other like I want. Also the solution is written in C#, which I have zero experience with. Here is what they wrote:

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1.Width + image2.Width, Math.Max(image1.Height, image2.Height));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);
        g.DrawImage(image2, image1.Width, 0);
    }

What I need is someone to go super high level with me and show me how this would sit in a aspx file and perhaps even how I would call it from one of my Classic ASP pages. I know I'm asking for a lot. I just don't know how it can be done another way, except for perhaps spending money I don't have on a commercial ActiveX component I can call from Classic ASP.

Thanks for any help or direction you can give!
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a composite of a lot of things, as you know! It would be suprising if somebody wrote it for you. I don't have the time.

BTW, a commercial component would be just as hard to interface with, and I'd challenge you to find one to do this obscure thing ;-)

#### Combinine the languages

Make a .NET 'class library' (dll or assembly) with your functionality, *not* an ASP.NET program. You can call that directly from classic ASP...
Like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248
Or this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1442595.aspx/1
Bottom line is, you check something in the .NET project options 'expose to Com/ActiveX', and then, classic ASP will see it.

#### Transfer the image in and out.

Simplest is to have the caller ASP generate a unique temp filename, save the file as that to the file system, pass the name to the .NET. I'll give pseudocode using that method.

You can pass the content as a large string, too, it could be converted in .NET using System.Text.Encoding. Safest would be base64, if you can go to and from that in ASP; strings might handle utf8, but if you get 'generic GDI+ error' from the .NET 'New Bitmap' line, the data is corrupt and the conversion is going wrong. First try the file method.

Note that in the file method sample I give, you'd replace the File names with Memory streams. which, you'd have to convert to/from the byte arrays. A few things to google, but if you can figure out ASP classic, you can figure that out using the search words I gave you.

#### Totally untested VB code to do the graphics

You will have to lean on Intellisense, help, and google just a tiny bit here if there are typos.

```
Public Sub DoubleImage(FileIn as string, FileOut as string)
    dim bmpIn as new Bitmap(FileIn)
    dim bmpOut as new bitmap(bmpin.width,bmpin.height*2)
    using g as new graphics.FromImage(bmpOut)
        g.drawimage(bmpin,0,0,bmpin.width,bmpin.height)
        g.drawimage(bmpin,0,bmpin.height,bmpin.width,bmpin.height)
    end using
    bmpout.save(FileOut)
end sub
```

Put this in a class library project, go to the properties and expose it to COM. Reference it from your ASP.

P.S. see the GDI+FAQ to learn how to grok .NET graphics: https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx

Comment: OMG thank you sooo much! This really met my need for high level help! This gets me started. Again, thanks! I want you to have as much credit as possible for this. At the same time, I don't want to "close the issue" by clicking "accepted answer" so I voted your answer up. I want this question to stay open for a bit so that others might want to throw in ideas or modifications to your idea. Like if anyone wants to toss some code my way to do any of the things you mention here. Your thoughts?

Comment: No. But just because my client has other priorities so this is on back burner for now.